# Max date over each item

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, group-by, maxdate

I have a table that simplified looks like this:

```
WITH TBL (ITEM, COST, DAY) AS (
  SELECT 'A', 6, TO_DATE('2019-08-13', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 4, TO_DATE('2019-08-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 4, TO_DATE('2019-08-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 2, TO_DATE('2019-08-21', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 5, TO_DATE('2019-08-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 2, TO_DATE('2019-08-15', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
) SELECT ITEM, COST, DAY FROM TBL;


ITEM | COST | DAY
-----+------+--------------------
A    | 6    | 2019-08-13 00:00:00
B    | 4    | 2019-08-21 00:00:00
B    | 4    | 2019-08-18 00:00:00
A    | 2    | 2019-08-21 00:00:00
B    | 5    | 2019-08-16 00:00:00
C    | 2    | 2019-08-15 00:00:00
```

I want to query the latest cost of each item.

```
ITEM | COST | DAY
-----+------+--------------------
B    | 4    | 2019-08-21 00:00:00
A    | 2    | 2019-08-21 00:00:00
C    | 2    | 2019-08-15 00:00:00
```

The way I do so is with a CTE getting the latest date of each item and then 
joining the cost.

```
WITH CTE (ITEM, DAY) AS (
  SELECT ITEM, MAX(DAY)
  FROM TBL
  GROUP BY ITEM
)
SELECT CTE.ITEM, TBL.COST, CTE.DAY
FROM CTE
JOIN TBL ON TBL.ITEM = CTE.ITEM AND TBL.DAY = CTE.DAY;
```

My question is if there's a simpler way to do it in one query without the CTE.

I tried to combine the MAX with the GROUP BY but didn't found any way to make it work.

```
SELECT ITEM, COST, MAX(DAY)
FROM TBL
GROUP BY ITEM, COST;
```

It only groups the records with the same item and cost when what I actually need is to group it accordingly with the MAX day.

```
ITEM | COST | DAY
-----+------+--------------------
A    | 6    | 2019-08-13 00:00:00
B    | 4    | 2019-08-21 00:00:00
A    | 2    | 2019-08-21 00:00:00
B    | 5    | 2019-08-16 00:00:00
C    | 2    | 2019-08-15 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is min/max with first/last option:

```
select item, max(day), max(cost) keep (dense_rank last order by day) from tbl group by item;
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d5d43221423cd0f6e12d3abeeabb3a6f)</sup>**

[Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm) to documentation and example.

Comment: It works. What does the `max(cost) keep (dense_rank last order by day)` exactly do?

Comment: It works like max, but criterium is not `cost`, but the day. So it finds value of cost  for last day. In case there are two such values max() takes greater. If you want lower use min().

Comment: Oh I see. I tried it out with an item having 2 different costs on the same date and could see that the max/min picks one cost while [forpas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57589945) picks both. Not too sure which answer to leave accepted since I don't think that happens but if it does I would probably only want 1 record to be returned so...

Comment: Though after trying to see if the other answer could also return one cost I found that it can by adding max/min to the cost and group by to the item and day. So both answers are correct and really good, can only accept one unfortunately but upvoted both.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number` analytical function which will number each row according to `partition by` and `order by` clause:

Try this:

```
SELECT ITEM, COST, DAY FROM
(SELECT t.ITEM, t.COST, t.DAY,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.ITEM ORDER BY T.DAY DESC) AS RN
FROM TBL t)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=90b92afa3e42958b20b7945a198c5a1d)

Cheers!!

Comment: That does seem correct even though I can't get it to work. Is it for Oracle 11g? I did tried to use OVER with PARTITION BY myself before asking but failed, also partition is mistyped in the code.

Comment: Sorry for typo mistake. And are you sure its not working. See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=90b92afa3e42958b20b7945a198c5a1d)

Comment: Nevermind it does work, just missing `()` after `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Cool. It happens but glad to know that it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT t.ITEM, t.COST, t.DAY
FROM TBL t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM TBL
  WHERE ITEM = t.ITEM AND DAY > t.DAY
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3073201d5c58df0610e567674cc96c48).
Results:

```
> ITEM | COST | DAY      
> :--- | ---: | :--------
> A    |    2 | 21-AUG-19
> B    |    4 | 21-AUG-19
> C    |    2 | 15-AUG-19
```

Comment: That works though I'm confused since I never used NOT EXISTS. Can you explain the logic?

Comment: It returns only the rows for which there does not exists another row for the same item with greater date. Meaning the result consists only from the rows with the latest dates for each item.